# Pressing F5 after 'EntityQuery.fromEntityKey' seems to clear the local cache with breeze

Tags: breeze

I develop an application with breeze. I needed to retrieve an entity with id=123 in local cache so I end up with the 1st scenario:

```
return manager.fetchEntityByKey("Transport", 123, true) // 3rd param is true --> local cache
              .then(fetchSucceeded)
              .fail(queryFailed);

function fetchSucceeded(data) {
        var s = data.entity;
        return s.isPartial() ? refreshTransport(s) : transportObservable(s);
}
```

Next I needed to expand some properties, so I end up with the 2nd scenario:

```
var entityType = manager.metadataStore.getEntityType("Transport");
var entityKey = new EntityKey(entityType, 123);
var query = EntityQuery.fromEntityKey(entityKey)
                       .expand("Sender.City, Sender.City.Country")
                       .using(breeze.FetchStrategy.FromLocalCache);

return manager.executeQuery(query)
              .then(fetchSucceeded)
              .fail(queryFailed);

function fetchSucceeded(data) {
     var s = data.results[0];
     return s.isPartial() ? refreshTransport(s) : transportObservable(s);
}
```

I perform some tests on the 2 scenarios and I noticed a difference when refreshing the browser (F5).

1st scenario: when pressing F5: the query is able to retrieve the data in local cache. So the user can press multiple times F5 and breeze will still use the local cache.

2nd scenario: when pressing F5: the query don't found anything in local cache then in `fetchSucceed` an error occurred with `s.isPartial()` because s in `undefined`.

**My question**: why refreshing the browser on the 2nd scenario seems to clear the local cache of breeze? How to proceed to avoid this behaviour?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Breeze always clears the local cache when F5 is pressed. F5 makes the browser to reload the entire page and every js pages are executed ( starting from main.js ).

You are seeing different behaviour because the third parameter in the fetchEntityByKey function instructs Breeze to search on local cache and if not found, make a request to the server.

In your second scenario, you are telling Breeze to fetch the entity from localcache ( .using(breeze.FetchStrategy.FromLocalCache); ) and because of that if the entity is not in local cache Breeze will never hit the server.